# Index over structures of arrays in Julia

Tags: julia

I have `Timeseries` structure in Julia as follows:

```
struct Timeseries
   timestamps::Vector{Int64}
   values::Vector{Float64}
end
```

I would like to define the subtimeseries `timeseries[i:j]` using the indices as follows:

```
timeseries[i:j] = Timeseries(timeseries.timestamps[i:j], timeseries.values[i:j])
```

However, I do not want to create or duplicate new objects (just as `values[i:j]` does not create a new array object from the original array `values` either) and want to use the stated syntax. How can I do that?

Comment: I'll have to point out that a structure like this [already exists](https://juliastats.org/TimeSeries.jl/stable/timearray/#The-TimeArray-time-series-type-1), if you're working with actual timed data.

Comment: @phipsgabler Thank you for pointing that out. The example I provided is a just simplified case of what I am working with which does not quite fit TimeArray struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your timeseries to just point to the original data you can use `view`s. If you relax your type definition a bit you can allow for putting views in there, and then overload `Base.view` for your type:

```
struct Timeseries{A<:AbstractVector{Int}, B<:AbstractVector{Float64}}
   timestamps::A
   values::B
end

function Base.view(t::Timeseries, idx...)
    return Timeseries(view(t.timestamps, idx...), view(t.values, idx...))
end
```

Example use:

```
julia> ts = Timeseries(collect(1:10), collect(0.0:10.0));

julia> view(ts, 1:5)
Timeseries{SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true},SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true}}([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])

julia> @view ts[1:5]
Timeseries{SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true},SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true}}([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
```

---

> just as values[i:j] does not create a new array object from the original array values either

Note that this is not true -- `values[i:j]` (which calls `getindex(values, i:j)`)  gives you a newly allocated array.

Comment: I would have suggested overloading `getindex` to use views, but this is even better, semantically.

Comment: Yea, and lets you use `getindex(::Timeseries, idx)` for the copying behavior.

Comment: I did not know that the array is copied from `values[i:j]`. That is quite memory inefficient! Although for many it may be the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although it is a pity I have to do `view(ts, 1:5)` instead of the plain `ts[1:5]`. In the end I decided just to use `ts.timestamps[1:5], ts.values[1:5]` instead of `ts2.timestamps, ts2.values` for `ts2 = [1:5]`.

Comment: I mean, you are free to change `view` to `getindex` and you get `ts[1:5]` as  you want.